# Firebase Popup positioning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

This has to have been answered already but I am having trouble finding it.

When using basic firebase authentication and using google pop up, is there anyway to postion the popup in the center of a screen. Its currently off to some random corner when I hit sign in with google.

Is this some sort of CSS styling. New to all of this stuff.

What I use to invoke firebase

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
firebase
  .auth()
  .signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then((result) => {
    /** @type {firebase.auth.OAuthCredential} */
    var credential = result.credential;

    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
    var token = credential.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    var user = result.user;
    setUser(user);
    setIsLogged(true);
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Yes, you will need to position the element with CSS.  The code you have here isn't relevant to your issue.  You would need to add the relevant html and css.  A codepen (or similar) would also be helpful.